# Lstlisting format Java code

Tags: lstlisting

If I'm writing in Netbeans, I can easily format my code. How do I do that in lstlisting? I mean, if I am import it or copy it into my TeX document with the right spaces, everything is fine. But is there another method? Can TeX do it automatically?

Comment: ``lstlisting`` of ``listing`` package can import a (raw) code files (ascii text) and keep the line breaking ogthis file.
So where is the problem ? What do you men by "with the right spaces" ?

Comment: May be here is the answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169669/can-listings-automatically-indent-code/169672

Answer (score 6):

You can try the following

```latex
\usepackage{courier} %% Sets font for listing as Courier.
\usepackage{listings, xcolor}
\lstset{
tabsize = 4, %% set tab space width
showstringspaces = false, %% prevent space marking in strings, string is defined as the text that is generally printed directly to the console
numbers = left, %% display line numbers on the left
commentstyle = \color{green}, %% set comment color
keywordstyle = \color{blue}, %% set keyword color
stringstyle = \color{red}, %% set string color
rulecolor = \color{black}, %% set frame color to avoid being affected by text color
basicstyle = \small \ttfamily , %% set listing font and size
breaklines = true, %% enable line breaking
numberstyle = \tiny,
}

\begin{lstlisting}[language = Java , frame = trBL , firstnumber = last , escapeinside={(*@}{@*)}]
public class Factorial
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   final int NUM_FACTS = 100;
        for(int i = 0; i < NUM_FACTS; i++)
            System.out.println( i + "! is " + factorial(i));
    }

    public static int factorial(int n)
    {   int result = 1;
        for(int i = 2; i <= n; i++) (*@\label{for}@*)
            result *= i;
        return result;
    }
}
\end{lstlisting}

And you can reference line \ref{for} in the code!
```

Here is the output

> [image: java]

Comment: It is not an MWE.